# Client-Server process inter-communication

Tags: linux

Client server must pass to the Server process a filename and the Server process must return the number of words in the file. My problem is that the filename contained in received variable is not seen as a filename, it tells me that such file or directory does not exist. Can you tell me why, please?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    int main(){
        char filename[30];
        printf("Give me the filename:\n");
        fgets(filename,30,stdin);
        int pfd1[2];
        int pfd2[2];
        pipe(pfd1);
        pipe(pfd2);
        int pid=fork();
        if(pid>0){
            char received[30];
            char ch;
            FILE *fp;
            read(pfd1[0],&received,30);
            fp=fopen(received,"r");
            int nrOfWords=0;
            while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
                if(ch==' ' || ch=='\0'){
                    nrOfWords++;
                }
            }
            printf("From server process: %s\n",received);
            write(pfd2[1],&nrOfWords,sizeof(nrOfWords));
            return 0;
        }
        if(pid==0){
            int receivedNumber;
            write(pfd1[1],&filename,30);
            read(pfd2[0],&receivedNumber,sizeof(receivedNumber));
            printf("From client process: %d\n",receivedNumber);
       }
  return 0;
```

}

Comment: Probably because `fgets()` doesn't remove the newline from the line it reads.

Comment: I'm afraid I can not see how this affects it...

Comment: Do your filenames have newlines in them?

Comment: You were right...I just added strtok(filename,"\n") after I read the filename and it works! Obviously, I have to change the second condition from the if in which I verify whether it is a space or an end line! Thank you very much!